# Three-dimensional Leibniz rule?

Tags: calculus

In deriving the equation of continuity, [one argument for it](http://books.google.ie/books?id=cmPDAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Lanczos%20variational%20principles&pg=PT337#v=onepage&q=%22The%20conservation%20of%20mass%22&f=false) is that if you consider a fixed volume $V$ in $m = \int_V \rho dV$ then $m$ is time-dependent, whereas if you consider a volume $V$ moving with the fluid then $m$ should become time-independent.

My question: How does one compute

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{V(t)} \rho dV$$

for a time-dependent volume? In other words, how do you generalize the [Leibniz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) to three dimensions?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem

Comment: Wow sweet, thanks!